# Select with where on partition key too slow with limit on Spark Sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am executing a query like 
`select <column> from <mytable> where <partition_key> = <value> limit 10`

and it is taking FOREVER to execute. I looked at the physical plan and I see a `HiveTableScan` in there and that looked fishy, does that mean the query is scanning the entire table? I was expecting the query to

A. exactly scan 1 partition and no more

B. end the scan as soon as it returns 10 rows

Is my understanding incorrect? How do I make spark perform exactly this?

Comment: LIMIT, but no ORDER BY?

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean? I don't have an order by in my query. It looks exactly like what I have mentioned. I think you mean orderby might need a global scan to do a full sort on the partition but definitely I am not asking it to do that

Comment: Without an ORDER BY those 10 rows will be just 10 arbitrary rows, but perhaps that doesn't matter?

Comment: It seems that your spark version doesn't optimize the limit grammer yet. What's the spark version you're using?

Comment: Please read [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/10465355) and [edit] your question  accordingly. At least we'll need a definition of the table, how it was created (Hive or Spark) and the execution plan.